# cannot add or apply the user defined package of TCL in Python

Tags: python, tcl

I have a TCL script that requires a user defined package within, when I run the TCL through python by the below script:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(
    "tclsh tcltest.tcl",
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print stdout
print stderr
```

returns the following error:

```
can't find package __teapot__

    while executing

"package require __teapot__"
```

the TCL works in tclsh environment! 
I believe that something is wrong in my setup that python doesn't recognize the package!

Comment: Does it work without python, i.e. when you start `tclsh tcltest.tcl` in a shell prompt? If it fails too, the question has nothing to do with python. If it succeeds, it would be a food for thought (what's the differences in the environments?).

Comment: yeah, it works in TCL. the problem is that python somehow doesn't find the required lib or I am not doing something in order that python recognizes the package!

Comment: Is current directory the same when you try it in python and shell?

Comment: what do you mean? I am not good at how the directories should be :)

Comment: Nevermind then. Create another TCL script, which will contain `"puts $::auto_path; puts [pwd]"`, name it `tcltest2.tcl`, start it with python and with shell, see if there are differences in the output.

Comment: I put the tcl script in python27 folder, added the command you said the the first line of my tcl script, then opened the python shell and wrote: import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(
 "tclsh tcltest2.tcl",
 shell=True,
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> stdout , stderr = p.communicate()
>>> print stdout

>>> print stderr
can't find package __teapot__

    while executing

"package require __teapot__"

Comment: "Added the command" -- does it mean that there is more than just my one-liner in `tcltest2.tcl`? Please remove. And by the way, I have an idea: what happens if you try `/usr/bin/tclsh` instead of `tclsh`, with both tcltest and tcltest2?

Comment: import subprocess
>>> p=subprocess.Popen(
 "/usr/bin/tclsh tcltest2.tcl",
 shell=True,
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> stdout , stderr = p.communicate()
>>> print stdout

>>> print stderr
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: and, what do you mean by remove? I added your suggested command to the first line of my script to see if it catch the package or not. if I remove everything else, what's the point of using it, how do I see whether ot not the package is added?

Comment: the point is to compare environments, specifically [pwd] and the value of $::auto_path, for tclsh-in-python and tclsh-not-in-python.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the environment variables are not passed in explicitly. How about:

```
import subprocess
import os
p = subprocess.Popen(
    "tclsh tcltest.tcl",
    env=os.environ,
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print stdout
print stderr
```

#### Update

Since that does not make any different, stick the following line into the first line of  *tcltest.tcl* file and compare the outputs:

```
puts ">>$auto_path<<"
```

I suspect the `auto_path` variable is different between the two cases. This variable is one way Tcl uses to locate packages.

Comment: This is hard to trace, because you could not execute tcl commands before tcl is initialized, but the initialization fails, and you need to execute some tcl commands to init it.